# On conflict not updating back to default values

Tags: postgresql, insert, elixir, ecto, upsert

I have a users table like this

```
create table(:users) do
  add(:email, :citext)
  add(:email_confirmation_token, :string)
  add(:email_confirmed_at, :utc_datetime)
  add(:deleted_at, :utc_datetime)

  timestamps()
end
```

and I have `User` schema as

```
schema "users" do
  field(:email, :string)
  field(:deleted_at, :utc_datetime)
  field(:email_confirmed_at, :utc_datetime)
  field(:email_confirmation_token, :string, default: ExApi.Utils.Random.string())

  timestamps()
end
```

Now if I insert record with on_conflict option I want to reset `deleted_at` but deleted_at is never passed to changeset. I used following line of code

```
attrs = %{"email" => "tanweer.shahzaad@gmail.com", "deleted_at" => nil}
cs = %User{} |> User.changeset(attrs)
ExApi.Repo.insert(cs, on_conflict: :replace_all, conflict_target: :email)
```

Any workaround which will reset `deleted_at` will be very much appreciated.

Problem: if `deleted_at` is already set, I want to reset it back to nil on insert

Comment: One way is check if user exists with that email(query) and deleted at is set then update that record

Comment: `on_conflict = [set: [deleted_at: nil]`
`Repo.insert(changeset, on_conflict: on_conflict, conflict_target: :email)`
Will this work for you ?

Comment: @DineshBalasubramanian No, it didn't work for me. I have tried this. Ecto didn't pick up deleted_at as a change